# 16.04 ucs 3260 cisco vic nic issue

Tags: networking

Has anyone been able to get Ubuntu 16.04's network working properly with the cisco ucs VIC ethernet?  I installed the appropriate drivers and the interface is up, but I can't send or receive packets. Basic network stuff is good mtu gateway route etc.

[image: lshw -C network]

Here's the answer,  in cms manager set vnic to trunk and set switchport mode trunk.  why if they are all on the same vlan????  because trunk means different things to different vendors, and they didn't follow their own standard.

Comment: We cannot intuit anything about your situation. You'll have to explain it.

Comment: okay,  the environment= ucs server s3260 with a single hardware node running 16.04 with the cisco vic drivers installed vic is set as an access port in csm 4x10gbps the cisco switch connected via 10gbps om4 mm fiber to a cisco access port and the appropriate vlan.  What details or output would you like to see?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer, in cms manager set vnic to trunk and set switchport mode trunk. why if they are all on the same vlan???? because trunk means different things to different vendors, and they didn't follow their own standard.